# Conditionally displaying interlaced or two-column content in CSS using media queries

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am designing a blog page which consists of text blocks and images. On a small screen, I would like my text and images to be interlaced; so the HTML flow should be the order in which the items appear on the page. Example:

```
Text1
Text2
Image1
Text3
Image2
Text4
Text5
Image3
```

On a wider screen, I would rather the items be displayed in two columns, with the text in the left column and the images in the right column. Example:

```
Text1   Image1
Text2   Image2
Text3   Image3
Text4
Text5
```

I want to attempt this using CSS media queries and no JS if possible.

I have tried several solutions already using flexbox and grid layouts. Grid has been the best option so far, since I am able to specify grid-column for all text and image objects, which lays them out in the correct columns. However, this approach results in a lot of whitespace where the image is much larger than the text in the same row. Using only one row causes all of the images and text to be overlayed on top of each other. Is there a way that I can have the items flow naturally inside of the first column?

My code right now:

```
.project-mainflow {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .project-mainflow {
        grid-template-columns: 40vw 40vw;
    }
    .project-image {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    .project-text {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Basically, CSS-Grid is not optimal here for your wider layout